# create custom UIButton using extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am new on iOS and Swift and I need some help.

I want create custom UIButton

Here is what I did

```
protocol ButtonProtocol {}


extension ButtonProtocol where Self: UIButton {

    func addOrangeButton(){
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex:ButtonColor.orange).cgColor
    }
}
```

I want all params came from here which are cornerRadius, backgrounColor, highlightedColor, textColor, size etc...

I want use this way bcoz maybe in future the button color will change I will change it from one place directly.

But I don't understand what is layer how could I cast it as UIButton?

Is anyone can tell me which way should I take ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the subclass of `UIButton`, to add your own custom look to your button. like this

```
import UIKit

protocol DVButtonCustomMethods: class {
func customize()
}

class DVButton: UIButton {
var indexPath: IndexPath?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    customize()// To set the button color and text size
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    customize()// To set the button color and text size
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    customize()
}

}

extension DVButton: DVButtonCustomMethods {
func customize() {
    layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tintColor = UIColor.red
    titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    clipsToBounds = true
}
}
```

Now what is need to do is, create one button in interface builder and assign you subClass as its class. Thats all everything will change as you want. If you want to change button colour just change in your subclass, it will affect in all button which is assigned your subclass.

**Assigning subclass to your button:** Refer below image

[image]

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

The way you defined the extension, doesn't make you able to use it in the `UIButton` instance so simple.

So, you can decide whether extend `UIButton` to conform the protocol, or you can create a subclass of `UIButton`

```
// in this way you can use the `addOrangeButton` method anywhere
extension UIButton: ButtonProtocol {}

// in this way your new subclass contains the addOrangeButton definition
// and a normal UIButton cannot access that method
final class OrangeButton: UIButton, ButtonProtocol {

    func setupButton() {
        addOrangeButton()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class func CutomeButton(bgColor: UIColor,corRadius: Float,hgColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, size: CGSize, titleText: String) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(corRadius)
    button.backgroundColor = bgColor
    button.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
    button.frame.size = size
    button.setTitle(titleText, for: .normal)
    return button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to modify a UIButton with specific parameters, let me tell you how do I do this:

```
extension UIButton
{
    func setRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

Use it as the following:

```
yourButton.setRadius(radius: 15)
```